# Performance got affected while movingfrom solr 1.4 to solr 5

Tags: solr

We have a very old collection running on solr 1.4. We had migrated it to solr 5.0 (latest when we started project). One of the issue we faced was, average indexing time per document increased from 0.3 sec to 4.5 sec (this is the total time from posting to solr till time got response). Couldn't understand the issue. Its just a normal migration and there were no customization.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a profiler to see where Solr spends its time after submitting the document? Does it happen in test as well as production?

Comment: Hi Mats ... sorry for late reply. Found the issue. There was one setting in Solr5 which is rebuilding "spellcheck dictionary" on each commit.